# How to transfer bitcoin to wallet

Tags: e-wallet

Bought a bitcoin from btcquick and i can not figure out how to transfer coin from there to my blockchain wallet with private key. Please help iv'e spent 3 days trying to get this all set up and i have a coin i can't get to.

Comment: Welcome on SE Bill, a word of caution: never reveal your private key to anybody. Addresses should be ok, but the private key immediately gives users access to the stored balance on that address.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good answer, as unfortunately I have no experience with btcQuick nor the blockchain wallet, yet it turned out to be too long for a comment.

I found a post btcQuick.com feedback forum:

> [...] btcQuick sent a .zip file containing a .pdf that had both a public and a private key (and QR codes for both). I scanned the private key into my blockchain app and sent the BTC to my main client.

So, after ordering Bitcoin from btcQuick you should have received an email with a .zip-file attachment. In that .zip-file you should have a .pdf file which contains both a private and public key, as well as a QR representation for each. From what I gather the blockchain app has a function to read in QR representations of private keys.

Have you tried using the blockchain app to import the private key?

Otherwise please provide more information with your question.